# SELECT TOP @Variable causes error: "Invalid syntax"

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Please see the TSQL below:

```
declare @NicheDailyDeletionVolume int
select @NicheDailyDeletionVolume = NicheDailyDeletionVolume FROM [hq-svr-sql-05].genie2delete.dbo.dbsystem
declare @tsql as nvarchar(200)
set @tsql = 'update tbx_rrdgeniestaging set addedtime = dateadd(d,-29,getdate()) where eventid in (
select distinct top '' + @NicheDailyDeletionVolume + '' eventid from tbx_rrdgeniestaging where candelete=getdate())'
EXECUTE sp_executesql @tsql
```

The error I get is: Incorrect syntax near ' + @NicheDailyDeletionVolume + '.

I have used variables like this before but never with TOP.

Comment: `WHERE  candelete = getdate()` is exceedingly unlikely to do what you want. Not clear what datatype `candelete` is from the name but assuming datetime from the comparison with `getdate()` will you really want to match only those rows with the exact time down to the milisecond as the query happens to be executed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Gareth points out in his deleted answer `TOP` without `ORDER BY` is meaningless anyway.

Syntactically you could parameterise it and pass it is in as a parameter to `sp_executesql`.

```
DECLARE @NicheDailyDeletionVolume INT

SELECT @NicheDailyDeletionVolume = NicheDailyDeletionVolume
FROM   [hq-svr-sql-05].genie2delete.dbo.dbsystem

DECLARE @tsql AS NVARCHAR(200)

SET @tsql = '
UPDATE tbx_rrdgeniestaging
SET    addedtime = dateadd(d, -29, getdate())
WHERE  eventid IN (SELECT DISTINCT TOP (@NicheDailyDeletionVolume) eventid
                   FROM   tbx_rrdgeniestaging
                   WHERE  candelete = getdate()) 

             '

EXECUTE sp_executesql @tsql, 
                      N'@NicheDailyDeletionVolume INT',
                      @NicheDailyDeletionVolume=@NicheDailyDeletionVolume
```

Though it isn't really apparent why you need dynamic SQL there at all.

TOP accepts an expression in parentheses so even the following would work

```
UPDATE tbx_rrdgeniestaging
SET    addedtime = dateadd(d, -29, getdate())
WHERE  eventid IN (SELECT DISTINCT TOP (SELECT NicheDailyDeletionVolume  
                                        FROM   [hq-svr-sql-05].genie2delete.dbo.dbsystem) 
                           eventid
                   FROM   tbx_rrdgeniestaging
                   WHERE  candelete = getdate())
```

But without an `ORDER BY` there's no guarantee which `eventid` you will end up with.